# Vertical bar sign in Discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I am little bit confused about the sign " | ".  Some people call it the division sign and some call it "such that".  In computer programming, it's known as pipe.

```
| => Such that sign
| => Division sign
| => Pipe sign
```

Comment: It has all three meanings, depending on context. In the second one, $a|b$ is often read verbally as "$a$ divides $b$".

Comment: LaTeX also offers a number of ways to evoke such a symbol.  You can just put "|" inside MathJax delimiters, or use `\mid` or `\vert`, etc.  See [this Q at TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vertical-bar-vert-lvert-rvert-divides) for details of what differences there are.  The vertical stroke is also used as a delimiter in absolute values and (doubled) in norms.

Comment: But what's your questoin?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The sign $|$ has a few uses in mathematics

$$\text{Sets }\{x\in\mathbb N\mid\exists y\in\mathbb N:2y=x\}$$

Here it the sign means "such that", the colon also means "such that" in this context

Note that in this case it is written `\mid` in LaTeX, and not with the symbol `|`.

---

$$a\mid b$$

In this case the $\mid$ sign means that $a$ divides $b$, or that $\frac ba$ is an integer

Note that in this case it is written `\mid` in LaTeX, and not with the symbol `|`.

---

$$|x|$$

Here it means the absolute value of $x$, ie. $|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x\quad&\text{if }x\ge0\\-x&\text{if }x<0\end{array}\right.$

In this case it is written with just the `|` symbol. Note that sometimes you need to put `{}` around the contents to get the correct spacing, ie.

- `|-2|` gives $|-2|$
- `|{-2}|` gives $|{-2}|$

---

```
$ ls -l | grep "Aug"
```

This use is from the unix terminal where it means that the output of the `ls -l` command is redirected to the command `grep "Aug"`, which shows all files last edited in august.

Note that this last one isn't really mathematics but I included it as you mentioned it.

Comment: I give up: What is in that set?

Comment: @BenJackson Woops seems like I had an $y$ instead of an $x$, but the mistakenly written set would be equal to $\mathbb N$, and the correct set are the even integers.

Answer (score 19):

In number theory the sign $\mid$ denotes divisibility.  But you need to **carefully note** that this is definitely not the same as division.

- "$2$ divided by $6$" can be written $2/6$ or $2\div6$.  Its value is one third, or $0.333\ldots\,$.
- "$2$ divides $6$" can be written $2\mid6$.  This is a **statement** and does not have any numerical value.  It says that $2$ goes into $6$ exactly with no remainder, or that $6$ is an integer times $2$.  This statement is true.
- Likewise, $3\mid7$ is the statement that $3$ goes into $7$ exactly with no remainder.  This statement is false.

It is very important to note (especially if English is not your first language) that "$a$ divides $b$" is very different from "$a$ divided by $b$".  Other ways of saying "$a$ divides $b$" are "$a$ is a factor of $b$" and "$b$ is a multiple of $a$".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, its help me..@David